# Do Dirichlet $L$-functions with greater modulus have a greater number of zeros lying off the critical line?

Tags: number-theory, roots, analytic-number-theory

Ignoring the GRH, for $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$, is it the case that
$$\sum_{primitive\chi\bmod{q}}N(\sigma,T,\chi)\geq\sum_{primitive\chi\bmod{d}}N(\sigma,T,\chi)$$
if $d|q$.  Of course, the zero density estimates available do not contradict this statement, but I was wondering if the statement is known to be true.

Comment: This isn't known.